# Handle a software programatically using java

Tags: java

I want to know that can we operate a simple software using java programming...i.e. if we know already what r the buttons there and what will be the flow after clicking any button, then can we programatically handle the flow?

Answer (score 4):

Check the the Java [java.awt.Robot](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, which can be used to control the mouse pointer and generate button clicks.